# Check if the value of the local storage is equal or not to that of a Php variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

hello I have this php file with the name ** request.php ** that has this Code:

> ```
> <?php
> $Password_user = 'AIzaSyA';
> ?>
> ```

and I have a **Index.html** file, and I also have a Local Storage with that name **user_pass** so I created a variable with the name **get_spass** that looks like this:
`var get_spass= localStorage.getItem('user_pass');`
so how can i create a request in Ajax that is able to check if the value of the Storage location is equal or not gives it Variable ** Password_user of **request.php**?

Comment: Why are you storing the password on the client machine? This is a gaping hole in security. The password should be known only to the user. Even the server shouldn't know it - it should only have a hashed version.

Comment: I use firebase for authentication, this variable will only be a complement to something that will be made public on the user's page!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your php file to:

```
<?php
$Password_user = 'AIzaSyA';
echo $Password_user;
?>
```

In your html file you can fetch the file and check the password value with this code:

```
var get_spass= localStorage.getItem('user_pass');
var passIsCorrect = checkPassword(get_spass);

if (passIsCorrect) {
    //do stuff...
}

async function checkPassword(get_spass) {
    const passwordPhp = await fetch("request.php");
    if (get_spass === passwordPhp) {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that everyone can get the request.php content. If the password need to be secret you have to implement some sort of authentication to assure the request.php file can be read only by authorized users or person.